# Wordpress and plugins (inventor) where posts table is defined

Tags: wordpress

I need to make some work with wordpress 4.9. The table prefix is defined as `abc_` and some posts is exists in table `abc_posts`. But also tables `abc_2_posts` and `abc_3_posts` is exists. Site catalog is actually rendered from `abc_2_posts`. Where this is configured?

Comment: This is because you have a multisite installation. The 2 in abc_2_posts is the id of one of the websites.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually an answer. Could you please create one to let me accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using a [`multisite installation`](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/). Every site in the network will have a unique id assigned to it. Looking at the table name `abc_2_posts` the number `2` tells you that this table is used by the site with id `2`.